# Save what's printing as a pdf

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, printing, print-preview

Some websites include a button to print off a webpage. This button often converts the webpage to a print-friendly view. How can I save this view of the webpage as an image or pdf?

For example, can I do so directly from my web-browser, can I intercept the correctly rendered page as it's being sent off to my printer, or will this require a case-by-case approach?

NB, the print button doesn't redirect me to a print-friendly web page, it just opens a print dialogue in situ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 has a PDF "Printer" by default; if the website's print button lets you choose a printer, simply choose that PDF printer. If it just dumps the print-friendly version of the page to the default printer, set your default printer to the Windows PDF printer, then go to the site and print it.